# Brightway2 - Get LCA scores of immediate exchanges

Tags: brightway

I'm having some problems regarding the post-processing analysis of my LCA results from brightway2. After running a LCA calculation, if, for example, I type top_activities() I get a list of a bunch of activities and their associated scores, however none of the activities/scores are the ones associated directly with my functional unit (they appear to be some exchanges of my exchanges...).

How can I get the LCA scores of the exchanges (both technosphere and biosphere) I defined when constructing my Functional Unit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty easy to traverse the supply chain manually, and everyone wants to do this a slightly different way, so it isn't built in to Brightway yet. Here is a simple example:

```
from brightway2 import *

func_unit = Database("ecoinvent 3.4 cutoff").random()

lca = LCA({func_unit: 1}, methods.random())
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()

print(func_unit)

for exc in func_unit.technosphere():
    lca.redo_lcia({exc.input: exc['amount']})
    print(exc.input, exc['amount'], lca.score)
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found the best way to get aggregated results for your foreground model in brightway is using the `bw2analyzer.traverse_tagged_databases()` function rather than `top_activities()`. Details in the docs are [here](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/technical/bw2analyzer.html#supply-chain-traversal).

It's designed to calculate upstream impacts of the elements of your foreground model and then aggregate the impacts based on a `tag` it finds in the activity. e.g. if you add `'tag':'use phase'` or `'tag':'processing'` to your activities you can aggregate impact results by life cycle stage.

BUT you can change the default label it looks for, so instead of `tag` you can tell it to look for `name` - that'll give you the aggregated upstream impact of each of the activities in your foreground model. It returns a dictionary with the names of your tags as keys, and impacts as values. It also returns a graph of your foreground system which you can use to create some cool tree/bullseye charts - see the [docs](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/technical/bw2analyzer.html#bw2analyzer.tagged.recurse_tagged_database) for the format.

Here's the function you need:

`results, graph = recurse_tagged_databases(functional_unit, method, label='name')`

Here are a couple of examples of the kinds of visualisations you can make using the data `recurse_tagged_databases` gives you:

Waterfall chart example from the results dictionary
[image: Waterfall chart example]

Bullseye chart example from the tagged graph
[image: Waterfall chart example]