# Is it possible for ".traverse_tagged_databases()" to look for the label in exchanges?

Tags: brightway

I'm trying to use "bw2analyzer.traverse_tagged_databases" to group the impact results of the exchanges (e.g., "electricity, medium voltage") of my functional unit activity (e.g., "production of a solar panel"), by a customized label (e.g., "group_tag"). However, it seems the method could not look for the label in these exchanges and all I get is this: "defaultdict(int, {'other': 97.25234998254226})".

So, I'm wondering if there is away to look for the label in exchanges?
Thank you!

Comment: have you considered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937878/how-to-use-the-transverse-tagged-databases-function-in-brightway2)?

Comment: Thx@Nabla, i followed instruction in that example, but the algorithm does not seem to pick up the tag in exchanges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, just Activities can be tagged and no Exchanges. 
You can traverse the supply chain manually as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197158/brightway2-get-lca-scores-of-immediate-exchanges/51300536#51300536).

Or as Workaround you can add Activities with the tag between the foreground and background Activity as shown here:

[image: Screenshot]