# Contribution analyses - tagged.database

Tags: brightway

I need to get the single contribution of the processes and emissions I filled into my database - similar to this problem : [Brightway2 - Get LCA scores of immediate exchanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197158/brightway2-get-lca-scores-of-immediate-exchanges)
it works for single methods but i was wondering how to get these results for several methods similar to when doing the ordinary calculations which can then be saved as csv? is there a way to create a loop for this?
Thank you so much!
Miriam

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called [`multi_traverse_tagged_database`](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-analyzer/blob/c20b8381cd25bc2a1c312ebdbca811addf85b930/bw2analyzer/tagged.py#L279) in `bw2analyzer` which should do what you need. It was part of a pull request so it's not in the docs.

I've copied in the docstring at the bottom which should give you some pointers. It's basically the same as the `traverse_tagged_database` function used in the question you've linked to, but for multiple methods. You'd use it like this:

`results, graph = multi_traverse_tagged_databases(functional_unit, list_of_methods, label='name')`

You should be able to use pandas to export the dictionary you get in `results` to a csv file.

```py
def multi_traverse_tagged_databases(
    functional_unit, methods, label="tag", default_tag="other", secondary_tags=[]
):

    """Traverse a functional unit throughout its foreground database(s), and
    group impacts (for multiple methods) by tag label.
    Input arguments:
        * ``functional_unit``: A functional unit dictionary, e.g. ``{("foo", "bar"): 42}``.
        * ``methods``: A list of method names, e.g. ``[("foo", "bar"), ("baz", "qux"), ...]``
        * ``label``: The label of the tag classifier. Default is ``"tag"``
        * ``default_tag``: The tag classifier to use if none was given. Default is ``"other"``
        * ``secondary_tags``: List of tuples in the format (secondary_label, secondary_default_tag). Default is empty list.
    Returns:
        Aggregated tags dictionary from ``aggregate_tagged_graph``, and tagged supply chain graph from ``recurse_tagged_database``.
    """
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! We figured out a way to iterate and get all impacts through all IA methods but only of the biosphere flows for some reason - We used traverse_tagged_database. It seems that i cant use multi_traverse_tagged_databases because it doesnt seem to be in my bw2analyzer package - i updated it but still i get an error message. Could you give me a hint on what i am doing wrong with the traverse function so that also the technosphere contributions appear or how to get the multi.. function into the package? thanks you so much and sorry for this follow question : )